# Facebook login popup flickering with django-allauth and docker

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, django-allauth

I am trying to integrate django-allauth with docker. While login with facebook getting error in console:

### Refused to execute script from 'https://www.localhost/static/facebook/js/fbconnect.js' because its MIME type ('image/png') is not executable.

And I have forcefully attached fbconnect.js file in layout and all functionality working fine but when I open popup for login with facebook then opened popup is flickering.
Why this is happening?
Please help.